# Error connecting to Twitter Streams API through docker

Tags: java, docker, twitter

I am having a strange issue when running my twitter streams application from docker. It works no problem when running through my IDE or directly running the JAR file. Does anyone know what may cause this? The error is:

```
[hosebird-client-io-thread-0] WARN com.twitter.hbc.httpclient.ClientBase - Hosebird-Client-01 Unknown host - stream.twitter.com

[hosebird-client-io-thread-0] WARN com.twitter.hbc.httpclient.ClientBase - Hosebird-Client-01 failed to establish connection properly
```

Java application: broadly copied from the twitter documentation

```
public Client createTwitterClient(BlockingQueue<String> msgQueue, List<String> terms) {

    /** Declare the host you want to connect to, the endpoint, and authentication (basic auth or oauth) */
    Hosts hosebirdHosts = new HttpHosts(Constants.STREAM_HOST);
    StatusesFilterEndpoint hosebirdEndpoint = new StatusesFilterEndpoint();

    hosebirdEndpoint.trackTerms(terms);
    Authentication hosebirdAuth = new OAuth1("myAPIKey","myAPISecret", "myBearerToken", "myTokenSecret");

    ClientBuilder builder = new ClientBuilder()
            .name("Hosebird-Client-01")
            .hosts(hosebirdHosts)
            .authentication(hosebirdAuth)
            .endpoint(hosebirdEndpoint)
            .processor(new StringDelimitedProcessor(msgQueue));

    Client hosebirdClient = builder.build();

    return hosebirdClient;

}
```

DockerFile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-slim
WORKDIR /root/kafka-producer-twittertweets
COPY target/kafka-producer-twittertweets-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar /root/kafka-producer-twittertweets
CMD java -jar kafka-producer-twittertweets-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

Comment: Are your running the docker container on your computer, is there maybe proxy issue ?

Can you bash into your container any try to ping or curl the twitter host, to make sure that it is a host resolution issue and has nothing to do with your app

Comment: when i curl the twitter host within the container it returns nothing. locally i can ping and it is fine. How do i fix the proxy issue?

Comment: Sorry and yes, I am running the container from docker toolbox for windows

Comment: Ping and curl work differently. Try curl outside the container